# using 1's and 0's of a binary code separately

Tags: java, android, binary

I have an integer variable that contains a binary number.
but I need to know how to use each number of the binary number (i.e. the 1 or 0) individually to perform a task accordingly.

To make it clearer I am working on a flashing application and I need to Turn the flash on if the number is 1 with a specific delay and turn the flash off if the number is 0 for a specific delay.

for example; the number "11" will be converted into "1011", then the flash will be turned on twice the delay time and turn off once then turned of once. 
How can the 1's and 0's of a binary number separately?

Comment: Study how `<<`, `>>`, `&` and `|` work on integers. That should get you through. Happy coding.

Comment: you can test the parity, and then shift right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int value = 0b1101;
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE; i++) {
    if (((value << i) & 1) == 1) {
        // turn on
    } else {
        // turn off
    }
}
```